# How to group numbered rows into groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Sql Server I need to take repeating sets of row numbers and group those into segments or sub groups.  I'm trying to achieve column B using Sql.  I've achieved column a using the row_number() function but I'm not sure how to get to Column B.

Here is the logic for row_number()

1 + ((row_number() over (order by TimeStamp, FileName, OrderID) - 1) % 5) AS [Row_Number]

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show the code you used to calculate `row_number()`.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I added more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `row_number()` is of the form:

```
row_number() over (partition by colA order by colB)
```

What you seem to want is:

```
dense_rank() over (order by colA)
```

That is, the partition key(s) used for the `row_number()` should be the `order by` keys for the `dense_rank()`.

EDIT:

Your code is:

```
1 + ((row_number() over (order by TimeStamp, FileName, OrderID) - 1) % 5) AS [Row_Number]
```

In this case, there is no `partition by`.  What you really want simply integer division.  This is easy:

```
1 + ((row_number() over (order by TimeStamp, FileName, OrderID) - 1) / 5) AS [Row_Number]
```

Comment: What a beautiful thing!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a simple solution:

```
SELECT [Row_Number], GroupNumber
FROM (
    SELECT [Row_Number]
        , row_number()over(partition by [Row_Number] order by [Row_Number]) as GroupNumber
        --Note: The order by clause above should be replaced with however you are ordering the groups of row numbers)
    FROM YourTableOrInlineView
    ) z
ORDER BY GroupNumber, [Row_Number]
```